# Mule ESB : Which has better performance -- scripts (java script,groovy,ognl etc ) or java code through Java component or transformer

Tags: mule, esb, mule-el, mule-component

I had this question in mind for long time and am jotting it down now.

Which will be a best practice or has an edge over others while transforming or processing data in Mule ESB. I am curious to differentiate between the following components.

1. Java Script
2. Groovy Script
3. Other allowed scripts

**VS**

Java Component or Java Transformer

Usually any ESB should provide various options for the transformations and Mule also provides a lot of ways and methodologies for transformation.

I am curios to know which is better for some of the common situations.

For example check the scenarios for below.

Calling a java component to chunk out a list from an object and make that list as the payload **VS** using OGNL in set payload component.

Comment: If needed I could quote more samples around this area to let you know more about my questions

Comment: I see another view point where when writing scripts we do not have any parsers to check if it has any errors or not and sometimes it becomes difficult for maintenance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OGNL is being [deprecated](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7757) in Mule.

Regarding Javascript vs Groovy vs MEL (MVEL) I would say it depends.

MEL scripts are the faster to start (find [here](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Performance+of+MVEL+2.0) some performance benchmarks), followed by Javascript (Mule still does not use Java 8's Nashorn) and followed by Groovy.

However, for very big tasks where initialization doens't matter that much groovy might still perform faster.

Anyhow, for almost the 100% of the cases, Java components, on equivalent tasks will perform faster than any other binding. This is due that Mule is written in Java and is doing straight API calls without using bindings or adaptations.

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot.. I figured that java is fastest and groovy is faster and other script is fast but wanted data points and you gave it in an link.